# Dumpsys-like functionality for apk app

Tags: java, android, adb, android-logcat

I am looking for a solution to access the internal state of our app from adb for debugging purposes. 
I have used dumpsys a lot to get the internal state of system services so now I wonder if I can expose an interface from our app to adb. The only thing I have thought of so far is to log the information periodically and then just read logcat but if possible I would like to be able to interact directly with the app over adb so question is how to implement this in our app.

Comment: sure: `adb shell dumpsys activity top` and override `Activity#dump` method, the same for `Service`, `ContentProvider` etc

Comment: @pskink this sounds awesome. Can I filter on the bundle id? Can I also interact in some way? Like sending commands to the app? If so please add an answer since then you covered my question in full

Comment: ok if you want to use some commands use: `adb shell dumpsys activity top any command line can be entered here` and get them from a last param passed to `Activity#dump` method, what bundle id?

Comment: so if the bundle id is se.jensolsson.testapp ? can I filter on this without using grep or something? Dont want to overload the device.

Comment: is your `Activity` started and visible? or you want to dump a custom `Service` running in a background? or `ContentProvider`? or something else?

Comment: It seem like targeting the server is probably best, got this to work but I wonder what the limits are. I tried on an Android 5.0 device and it did not work. If I run adb shell dumpsys activity -p se.jensolsson.app service se.jensolsson.app.service, it gives me Unknown argument: -p; use -h for help

Comment: yes indeed: run `adb shell dumpsys activity -h` or see http://ar-g.github.io/ADB-Shell-Part-3/ and ^F `adb shell dumpsys activity -h`

Comment: @pskink I cannot see how I can dumpsys activity on a service on android 5.0. -h returns the following

Comment: `service [COMP_SPEC]: service client-side state` - see `adb shell dumpsys activity -h`

Comment: Thanks found it! It worked!

Comment: but remember: your service has to be started and COMP_SPEC does not have to be full service class name - in most cases you can simply use just class name, like `MySuperService`

Comment: from `dumpsys activity -h`: *"COMP_SPEC may be a component name (com.foo/.myApp),
    a partial substring in a component name, a
    hex object identifier."*

Comment: @pskink can you please add this as an answer since it is really the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your `Activity` override `dump()` method, for example:

```
@Override
public void dump(String prefix, FileDescriptor fd, PrintWriter writer, String[] args) {
    //super.dump(prefix, fd, writer, args);
    writer.println();
    writer.println("command line arguments:");
    writer.format("length: %d, args: %s", args.length, Arrays.toString(args)).println();
}
```

then start your `Activity` and type in the terminal:

`adb shell dumpsys activity top your cmd line arguments`

or:

`adb shell dumpsys activity top`

if you don't want to pass any arguments to `dump()` method

the same method exists in other components like `Service` or `ContentProvider` - see their official documentation on how to invoke them by using `adb shell dumpsys activity` command, also there are classes that have their `dump()` methods that can be used to dump their internal state - for example `ApplicationInfo`, `ActivityInfo`, `Looper`, `Handler`, `Binder`, `Fragment` and many others