# Android: Listen to custom ADB/terminal commands

Tags: android, adb

While [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) can do lots of thing to perform some changes or actions in the android device. Is there some way to send custom command that every app can tailor based on their needs?

One example would be: `adb CUSTOM_COMMAND [PARAM]`. If the available commands in ADB are not easy to edit, then something like `adb run -CUSTOM_COMMAND [PARAM]`. 
Then the app would be able to listen to that command and parse what are the instruction it needs to do.

Is this possible using ADB or any other tools?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915233/2252830

Comment: Thanks @pskink! It's the answer I'm looking for. Please reply as answer below and I'll accept it.

Comment: then upvote the answer in the link i posted