# Is it possible to return a value when calling broadcast from adb?

Tags: android, adb

I'm developing a program in VB.NET which gonna syncronize the Android device via USB.

Actually the program send some broadcast which is saying to the device that the syncronization has been started then pulling out the file and deleting it from the device.

The issue is that if i call

```
adb shell am broadcast -a xx.xxx.xxxx.android.action.broadcast --es sync ""SYNC""
```

In any case even if the `BroadcastReceiver` hasn't yet been registered in the app or even if the app is closed return

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=xx.xxx.xxxx.android.action.broacast pkg=WE (has extras) }
Broadcast completed: result=0
```

So i need to ensure the user that the device has received that broadcast so is it possible in someway send a "return" message to adb when the device has received that broadcast?

here is my `BroadcastReceiver` method

```
private final BroadcastReceiver adbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            if (extras.getString("sync") != null) {
                if (Alerts.dialogSync.isShowing()){
                    Alerts.txtSync.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#E91E63"));
                    Alerts.txtSync.setText("Sincronizzo..");
                    Alerts.syncProgress.setColor(Color.parseColor("#E91E63"));
                    Alerts.close.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else if (extras.getString("endsync") != null) {
                Alerts.dialogSync.dismiss();
                alertDeleteFile();
                unregisterReceiver(adbReceiver);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: inside your BroadcastReceiver write a message into LogCat, and listen to this message in your VB app

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/51915233/2252830, no need for any broadcasts and logcat listening